# Can WKWebView load local HTML5 for writing?

Tags: swift, macos, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

I'm trying to do something like hybird with WKWebView.
I finished the HTML5 pages, and let it displayed in WKWebView in a macOs App.
All things go well, but I can't input any character into the  field in the macOs WKWebView.
My question is: Is there any way to let the  field can be input text in macOs WKWebView?

FYI, follow code can enable input for the  field: wkWebView.load(URLRequest.init(url: URL.init(string: "http://localhost:4200")!))

FYI, follow code can't input any thing for the  field:
wkWebView.loadFileURL(indexUrl, allowingReadAccessTo: readAccessUrl)

How can I let the  field be enabled to input, with the loadFileURL method?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the reason caused the problem: As I set the WindowMask in WindowController. Thanks All.